# add the add-in icon in the calendar section of outlook

Tags: outlook, office365, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

hello guys is there any way to add the addin icon in the calendar section of outlook i have tried some extension but it does not work

```
 <Host xsi:type="AppointmentAttendeeCommandSurface">
    <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
      <Label resid="paneReadLabel" />
      <Control xsi:type="Button" id="paneReadButton">
        <Label resid="paneReadLabel" />
        <Supertip>
          <Title resid="paneReadTitle" />
          <Description resid="paneReadDescription" />
        </Supertip>
        <IconUrl>icon-32.png</IconUrl> <!-- Replace with the actual icon URL -->
        <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
          <SourceLocation resid="taskPaneUrl" />
        </Action>
      </Control>
    </OfficeTab>
  </Host>
```